# Distance from origin when (X,Y) are uniformly distributed

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables

Let's say that $X$ and $Y$ are two independent random variables with distribution $U(0,c)$. If a point on the Cartesian plane is defined by $(X,Y)$, then the distance from the origin is the random variable $S = \sqrt{ X^2 + Y^2}$. What would the distribution or expected value of $S$ be? The set of possibilities is the $c$ by $c$ square in the first quadrant. If you apply the assumption that $S \le c$, then values of S correspond to concentric quarter-circles, so that you can use geometry to find $P(a\le S\le b \mid S \le c)$   $$P(a\le S\le b \mid S \le c)=\frac{b^2-a^2}{c^2}$$ But without the simplifying assumption, I have no clue about this problem, as my knowledge of random variables is very basic.

Comment: If $X$ and $Y$ are just two random variables with distribution $U(0,c)$ you cannot say what the distribution of $S$ is.

Comment: What @geetha290krm means is that you have to specify how $X$ and $Y$ depend on each other. For instance we could have them be independent, or $X=Y$ or $X=c-Y$, all of those can work and lead to very different answers.

Comment: Will add edit stating they are independent

Comment: I tried to find the area belonging to $S \le r$ when $r \gt c$, and got an expression that looks impossible to simplify: https://imgur.com/a/Uym9Nq8

Answer (score 2):

Giving the CDF is enough to specify the distribution. That being said, try and draw pictures to understand what's happening.

That being said $\{S\leq a\}=\{x^{2}+y^{2}\leq a^{2}\}$

So there are three cases $0\leq a^{2}\leq c^{2}$ , $c^{2}\leq a^{2}\leq 2c^{2}$ and $a\geq 2c^{2}$

Note that in the third case $P(S\leq a)=1$

And in the first case it is just $\displaystyle\frac{\pi^{2}a^{2}}{4c^{2}}$

It is the 2nd case that is bothersome.

Note that when $c^{2}\leq a^{2}\leq 2c^{2}$ , the curve $x^{2}+y^{2}=a^{2}$ meets the line $x=c$ and $y=c$ at $(c,\sqrt{a^{2}-c^{2}})$ and $(\sqrt{a^{2}-c^{2}},c)$ respectively.

So the area of the quadrant that lies inside the square would be given by

$$c\sqrt{a^{2}-c^{2}}+\int_{\sqrt{a^{2}-c^{2}}}^{c}\sqrt{a^{2}-x^{2}}\,dx$$

So $$P(S\leq a)=\frac{c\sqrt{a^{2}-c^{2}}+\int_{\sqrt{a^{2}-c^{2}}}^{c}\sqrt{a^{2}-x^{2}}\,dx}{c^{2}}$$

This completely specifies the CDF.

Here are the 3 cases

Case 1

[image]

Case 2
[image]

Case 3

[image]

$$E(S)=\frac{1}{c^{2}}\int_{0}^{c}\int_{0}^{c}\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}}\,dxdy$$

It is advisable that you use Polar coordinates now.

Note that you can divide the square into two parts by the diagonal $x=y$ .

So we can focus on one part and then multiply it by $2$ as due to symmetry, the integrals on both parts will be equal.

The part of the square below the diagonal is parametrized by $\{0\leq r\leq c\sec(\theta),0\leq \theta\leq \frac{\pi}{4}\}$.

[image]

So the integral in this region would become $$\frac{1}{c^{2}}\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\int_{0}^{c\sec(\theta)}r\cdot r\,drd\theta$$ (Note that we get one $r$ from $\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}}$ and another one from the Jacobian Determinant to change from Cartesian to Poalr)

So $$E(S)=\frac{2}{c^{2}}\cdot\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\int_{0}^{c\sec(\theta)}r\cdot r\,drd\theta$$

I'll leave the calculations of the integrals to you.